# How to publish Android framework to Azure artifact feed?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is the first time that I'm trying to build and publish a Android Framework, so other developers can add in their app as dependency. Basically did the same thing for iOS, using CocoaPods, just adding the URL of my repo worked. But for Android seems to be more challenging.

So, this is what I have

**root/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def GROUP_ID = ''
def ARTIFACT_ID = ''
def VERSION = '0.1.0'
def ARTIFACT = ''
def URL = 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../maven/v1'
def USERNAME = '';

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/publish-package-gradle?view=azure-devops#configure-buildgradle
publishing {
    publications {
        myPublication(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${GROUP_ID}"
            artifactId "${ARTIFACT_ID}"
            version "${VERSION}"
            artifact "${ARTIFACT}"
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "${URL}"
            credentials {
                username "${USERNAME}"
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
        }
    }
}

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/publish-package-gradle?view=azure-devops#configure-buildgradle
repositories {
    maven {
        url "${URL}"
        credentials {
            username "${USERNAME}"
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**root/MyLib/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'kotlin'
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

When I run `gradle build`, I get the following error:

```
Gradle sync failed: No signature of method: build_...publishing() is applicable for argument types: (build_...$_run_closure1) values: [build_...$_run_closure1@29c0154f]
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (5 s 384 ms)
```

Following azure instructions I did add the settings.xml file in ${user.home}/.m2

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>MyLib</id>
      <username>myusername</username>
      <password>[PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN]</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by wrapping the `publishing {}` in `afterEvaluate`:

```
    afterEvaluate {
        publishing {
           ...
        }
    }
```

Following [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin)